# What is a good frequency for merging up feature branches to a main line?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial

We have a very large code base in mercurial.  We have about a 6 month release cadence with 2 week sprints.   For each release we have about 10 feature branches and maybe 5 or so people working per branch.

Now whether or not feature branches are a [good idea](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FeatureBranch.html) is a question for another day.

Currently we do merge-downs/copy-ups from feature branches into the main QA line twice during that 6 months - once about 1/2 way through and once a few weeks before the end of the release.  (specifically, merge-down from qa, then feature branch copies up).

The reason seems not to keep in sync with each other, but to enable some testing about half-way through the release.

This has caused a lot of angst about looming merges and a few nasty merge conflicts, but not as many as one might expect.

So I guess my questions are:

-Would having more frequent merges just for the sole purpose of keeping things in sync and preventing surprises create more churn or less churn?

-If so, what would be a good schedule?    I've thought about this a bit - more frequent merges would require teams to have their code in good shape more often, which might not be a bad thing.  Too often though might spread bugs around to all feature branches before they get a chance to be fixed.

We're using Hg, but I'm adding git as a tag because I think the issues are pretty much the same.